# Laravel: eager loading user for navbar

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a user with a hasMany relationship "animals".

In the navbar the first animal result will be shown and how many he collected.

```
{{Auth::user()->animals()->first()->name}}
{{Auth::user()->animals()->first()->amount}}
```

This produces two sql queries.

*Since this is the navbar what is a safe way to always load the user into the $user variable?*

*If I use Auth::user() how can I eager load animals?*

*Does a global user variable make sense or is it better and more secure that the controller always passes the $user to the view?*

This code also produces three queries:

```
$user=Auth::user();
$user->load('animals');
echo     $user->animals()->first()->name;
echo     $user->animals()->first()->amount;
```

I assume first() is the culprit. *What is the correct and simplest way to access the first element of an eager loaded collection?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing in a right way except

```
$user=Auth::user();
$user->load('animals');
echo     $user->animals()->first()->name;
echo     $user->animals()->first()->amount;
```

Change this to this

```
$user=Auth::user();
$user->load('animals');
echo     collect($user->animals)->first()->name;
echo     collect($user->animals)->first()->amount;
```

Or you can also do like this

```
$user=Auth::user();
$user->load('animals');
echo     $user->animals->first()->name;
echo     $user->animals->first()->amount;
```

When you do  `echo $user->animals()->first()->name;` it refers to the model which executes the query. But `$user->animals->first()->name` refers to the collection which is already loaded using `load()`

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. The second example is perfect and load is in this case not even necessary. I tried it without and it still only executes one sql query.